# Spring Boot Config Client is not fetching property from Config Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am able to start Config Server and can load profiles via http://localhost:8888/customer-microservice/dev as shown below 
[image]

I am trying to test via controller present in spring client application as below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class CustomerMicroserviceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CustomerMicroserviceApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@RestController
@RefreshScope
public class GreetController {

    @Value("${name}")
    private String personName;

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greet(){
        return "hello " + personName;
    }
}
```

Configuration present inside bootstrap.yml is as below :
[image]

While starting the client application, it's failing with error as Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'name' in value "${name}"

I think the client application is unable to contact the config server.

I browsed  a lot to fix this issue but I am unable to understand the problem.
Kindly help as I am new to spring cloud.

Complete pom.xml of Customer-microservice as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.microservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>customer-microservice</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <name>customer-microservice</name>
    <description>Spring Boot and Spring cloud microservice</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Required for service discovery client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Does your `customer-microservice` is trying to start on port 9000?

Comment: @veben yes. It's trying to start on port 9000 and it's starting succussfully if I remove that Value annotation

Comment: put the values you configured in git repo into application..properties of customer-microservice.then issue will go away.